Should I share my idea for a grant with a potential competitor?
I'm a fairly new postdoc, about to meet with another new postdoc in my field for a coffee. I'm really excited to share one particular idea for a grant proposal with them, as I think they could be an ideal collaborator on this proposal. However I've never met this person before, and despite all appearances being favourable, I am worried that they could take the idea and run with it.
What are some ways to ensure that this doesn't happen? I want to be able to share the idea without risk of being scooped, but also without being too precious with my idea (I know it's just an idea at this stage, but I still think it could have legs).

Why are you so anxious about this person, and why would you consider inviting them to collaborate if you think they might steal your idea?

Trust but verify. Given the potential for a collaboration - yes, you should share your idea with them. Take the risk. At the same time, think of ways to mitigate the risk: perhaps follow with an email mentioning in writing what you shared with them or perhaps have a third person join the meeting. Either way, and before sharing your idea, ensure that they're interested in a potential collaboration. If they're not or if they're hesitant - keep your idea to yourself and only share it when the other side understands the need to play fair. Good luck.

Ideas are cheap, and until you put them into action, they are fair game. How do you know your potential collaborator hasn't had similar/related ideas? Or other people for that matter?
If you are hesitant and want to protect your ideas, then I suggest you begin working on a proposal on your own, and then carve out a space for the potential collaborator to contribute to. That way it is clear that you are adding them to an existing concept paper/project (not that it will guarantee they don't strike out on their own at some point, but it gives you more credence as the originator).
Besides, how do you know that this person wants to collaborate with you, is compatible with you? How do you know that you will actually want to collaborate with them? Fruitful collaborations take a lot of moving parts, and even if everything looks good on paper, there is no guarantee it will work out to everyone's benefit in the end.
